# An unlucky person whose fortune doesn't favor them

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

Please imagine a person who is usually unlucky! The peron faces another unlucky situation and wants to criticize it and make a pejorative remark about his luck and relate his belief about the lack of his chance since old times ago! We have a proverb here which figuratively says:

> - **Literal translation:** My donkey didn't have any tail since it was a foal!
> - **Connotation:** As far as I can remember, I've always been unlucky!

I have found the following saying which I have no any idea whether etymologically it has something to do with the concept in my question or not:

> - **I have no pretention to begin with!**

I would appreciate it if you help me to find the closest proverb/expression/idiom to describe this concept in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not nearly as colorful, but I think the most common thing people would say here is, "Just my luck!", "Isn't that just my luck?", or even, "If it wasn't for bad luck, I'd have no luck at all."

I'm not personally familiar with the expression, "I have no pretention to begin with!" But it sounds like it is more about self regard or a pretention to status than it is about luck.